# how do i fix my layout showed transparent view in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Hello  I have Create one Activity and it have 3 fragment class.I am facing problem like if i call fragment its background is transparant and i can see previous fragment or activity can also see and perform action on it.

i need to fix this solution.
how it is possible.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "call fragment"? are you using add() or replace()?

Comment: Bundle argu = new Bundle();
     argu.putString("userId", UserId);
     Add_Password addPassword = new Add_Password();
     addPassword.setArguments(argu);
     getFragmentManager()
     .beginTransaction()
     .replace(android.R.id.content, addPassword)
     .addToBackStack(null)
     .commit();

Comment: Calling means i am calling fragment OnClickListener on Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add properties to the top view of the Fragment's layout:

```
android:background="#fff"
android:clickable="true"
```

Its should solve the problem

`android:clickable="true"` could be enough but I didn't test it.